# Added wrong path to $PATH variable but can't find old varaible to delete it

Tags: bash, python, environment-variables, paths

I'm trying to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to set up and IDE for Python, following a tutorial for this on Ubuntu I accidentally entered the wrong path to the virtualenvwrapper. When I try to source the .bashrc I get the following error

```
 -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
 -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I can't find these directories being listed in my path variable, and thus, can't remove them. How would I find and remove these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PATH` is usually set up in `${HOME}/.bashrc, the file you`source`d. To see which line, you could type:

```
grep -n virtualenvwrapper ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

Redo the step of the "tutorial for this on Ubuntu" (no actual link, and why should I go read it anyhow?) that had you entering the `PATH`, or edit `${HOME}/.bashrc` yourself.

Comment: This worked, I didn't put in the link because I believed it to be pointless, the problem was more with changing the path variable rather than the tutorial itself.  Will mark as answer.